# How do I keep reactivity when combining v-bind with filters

Tags: vue.js

I've got the following input box which is populated from an object correctly

```
<input type="text" :value="value.delayed_till | dateFilter" readonly>
```

The following filter is applied:

```
filters: {
    dateFilter: function (value) {
      const months = [
        'January',
        'February',
        'March',
        'April',
        'May',
        'June',
        'July',
        'August',
        'September',
        'October',
        'November',
        'December'
      ]
      let seconds = new Date(value.seconds * 1000)
      let year = seconds.getFullYear()
      let month = months[seconds.getMonth()]
      let day = seconds.getDate()
      let hour = seconds.getHours()
      let min = seconds.getMinutes()
      return day + ' ' + month + ' ' + year + ' ' + (hour < 10 ? '0' : '') + hour + ':' + (min < 10 ? '0' : '') + min
    }
  }
```

However when the value of the input box is updated the corresponding object (from which the value was taken) does not change.

For all my other input boxes I use v-model which does does update the object when the value of the input box is changed

Vue [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html) advises to use v-bind but that gives me an error:

```
<input type="text" v-bind="value.delayed_till | dateFilter" readonly>
```

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "dateFilter" is not defined on the
> instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
> reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
> initializing the property.

Comment: When you used `<input type="text" :value="value.delayed_till | dateFilter" readonly>`. the `:value` of the input was binded to `yourvuecomponent.$data.value.delayed_till`, so when `value.delayed_till` was updated by other components, it should corresponding update the `:value` of the above component. Did you get any error message in this case (`:value=` not `v-bind=`)?

Comment: There are no errors when using `:value=`. But when I log the corresponding object, I see that the changes are not updated.

Comment: The component you put above has nothing to do with updating the object, it's `readonly`. If there's an error when updating the object, it must be in the components those `v-model` with *(update)* that object. Try to diagnose them. not the one above.